# php вывести меню

Tags: php, php7, menu

есть таблица `content`
структура

```
id
name
url
parent
```

как мне вывести меню в таком виде (Если в меню второго уровня нет подменю, то их группировать в `li class="categories"`)

```
<ul class="topmenu">
     <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Каталог</a>
         <ul>
             <li class="category"><a href="">Подпункт с подкатегориями</a>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="">Подподкатегория</a></li>
                  </ul>
             </li> 
             <li class="category"><a href="">Подпункт с подкатегориями</a>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="">Подподкатегория</a></li>
                  </ul>
             </li> 
             <li class="categories">
                 <a href="">Подпункт без  подкатегорий</a>
                 <a href="">Подпункт без подкатегорий</a>
             </li>               
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Исправь ошибки. Я честно не понял что тебе нужно.

Comment: извиняюсь, убрал ошибки

Comment: Без рекурсии вам здесь не обойтись.
Глубина вложенности ограничена у вас?

Comment: 3 уровня, в таблице есть поле parent - это родитель

Comment: @extrememod да, я только заметил. А чём проблема, собственно? Добавьте код хотя бы, как вы рендерите меню своё... Так-то вам просто надо в классе добавить переменную, аля `$menu_type` и когда данные берёте с базы в неё вписывать sub-item какой-то, и у самого рендера уже проверять тип и если он == 'sub-item' то рисовать его как подменю

Comment: тут единственная проблема будет с классами categories и category, ибо нужно провнюерять сначала есть ли у детей списка свои дети. без них выводится рекурсивно очень просто. как по мне легче их вывести без этих классов, и добавлять их уже в браузере через js

Answer (score 0):

Многоуровневое.

```
$menu = [
    ['id'=>'1', 'name' => 'Пункт 1', 'url' => '#', 'parent' => null],
    ['id'=>'2', 'name' => 'Пункт 2', 'url' => '#', 'parent' => null],
    ['id'=>'3', 'name' => 'Пункт 3', 'url' => '#', 'parent' => null],
    ['id'=>'4', 'name' => 'Подпункт 1', 'url' => '#', 'parent' => 1],
    ['id'=>'5', 'name' => 'Подпункт 2', 'url' => '#', 'parent' => 3],
    ['id'=>'6', 'name' => 'Подпункт 3', 'url' => '#', 'parent' => 5],
    ['id'=>'7', 'name' => 'Подпункт 4', 'url' => '#', 'parent' => 5],
    ['id'=>'8', 'name' => 'Подпункт 4', 'url' => '#', 'parent' => 7],
    ['id'=>'9', 'name' => 'Подпункт 4', 'url' => '#', 'parent' => 7],
    ['id'=>'10', 'name' => 'Подпункт 4', 'url' => '#', 'parent' => 7],
];

function getChild($id, $menu){
    $return = false;
    foreach ($menu as $child){
        if($child['parent'] == $id){
            $childItem = '<a href="">'.$child['name'].'</a>';
            if($childs = getChild($child['id'],$menu)){
                $return .= '<li class="category">'.$childItem.$childs.'</li>';
            }else{
                $return .= '<li class="categories">'.$childItem.'</li>';
            }
        }
    }
    if($return){
        $return = '<ul>'.$return.'</ul>';
    }
    return $return;
}

?>



<ul class="topmenu">
<?php
foreach ($menu as $item) {
        if (is_null($item['parent'])) {
            echo '<li><a href="">' . $item['name'] . '</a>'.getChild($item['id'], $menu).'</li>';
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, что при `вытаскивании` меню из БД и формировании результата имеется схожая структура, конечный уровень вложенности меню неизвестен:

```
$menu = [
            [
                'name' => 'Главная',
                'url' => 'mydomain.com',
                'categories' => []
             ],

             [
                'name' => 'Продукты',
                'url' => 'mydomain.com/products',
                'categories' => [
                    [
                       'name' => 'Категория_1',
                       'url' => 'mydomain.com/products/category1',
                       'categories' => []
                    ],   
                    [
                       'name' => 'Категория_2',
                       'url' => 'mydomain.com/products/category2',
                       'categories' => [
                           [
                               'name' => 'Подкатегория_категории_2',
                               'url' => 'mydomain.com/products/category2/subcategory1',
                               'categories' => []
                           ]  
                    ],
                ], 
             ],
         ],
    ];
```

Поскольку вложенность неизвестная, целесообразно применить рекурсию. Тогда код вывода меню выглядит следующим образом:

```
function showMenu($menu){
    if(empty($menu['categories'])){
        echo "<li><a href=". $menu['url'] .">".$menu['name']."</a></li>";
    }else{
        echo "<li><a href=".$menu['url'].">".$menu['name']."</a><ul class='submenu'>";
        foreach($menu['categories'] as $item){
            showMenu($item);
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

foreach($menu as $item){
    showMenu($item);
}
```